# Changing Chart colour scale in loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with data organized into categories in the column "variable".  I would like to produce a separate geom_point() chart for each category and I would like to specify the colour of the chart depending on the value of the category in the column "variable" as well as a legend for each chart.  I do not want to use facetting to do this, because my actual use case is much more complicated than this one.

Here is some sample code:

```
df <- rbind(data.frame(date = 1:100, value = rnorm(100, 0, 1), variable = "a_variable"),    
            data.frame(date = 1:100, value = rnorm(100, 0, 1), variable = "b_variable"))

a_list_of_colours <- list()    
a_list_of_colours[["a_variable"]] <- "red"    
a_list_of_colours[["b_variable"]] <- "blue"
```

## Loop 1

```
a_list_of_charts <- list()   

for(i in 1:length(a_list_of_colours)){

  print(a_list_of_colours[[i]])

  a_list_of_charts[[i]] <- ggplot(df %>% 
                                    filter(variable == names(a_list_of_colours)[i]), 
                                  aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable)) +
    geom_point(shape = 19, size = 2) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = a_list_of_colours[[names(a_list_of_colours)[i]]])

}
```

## Loop 2

```
a_list_of_charts <- list()

for(i in 1:length(a_list_of_colours)){

  print(a_list_of_colours[[i]])

  a_list_of_charts[[i]] <- ggplot(df %>% 
                                    filter(variable == names(a_list_of_colours)[i]), 
                                  aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable)) +
    geom_point(data = df, aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable),
               shape = 19, size = 2, 
               colour = a_list_of_colours[[names(a_list_of_colours)[i]]])
}
```

## Loop 3

```
a_list_of_charts <- list()

for(i in 1:length(a_list_of_colours)){

  print(a_list_of_colours[[i]])

  a_list_of_charts[[i]] <- ggplot() +    
    geom_point(data = df %>% 
                 filter(variable == names(a_list_of_colours)[i]), 
               aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable),
               shape = 19, size = 2,
               colour = a_list_of_colours[[names(a_list_of_colours)[i]]])
}
```

I would like any of these loops to produce two charts, one in red and one in  blue dots.  I am primarily curious as to why the first loop, passing values to `scale_colour_manual()` doesn't work and always produces blue charts.  However, I am also interested in a solution.  I am oddly unable to produce legends with the second two loops by passing the variable so an aesthetic within geom_point().  Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Loop 1

Try updating your ggplot2 package version to the latest (3.1.0), and it should work correctly (at least it did on mine). Suspect it's due to [this change](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2807) for forced arguments, though I don't know the underlying details sufficiently to be sure.

## Loop 2

This code has a problem: When you supply a data argument in both `ggplot()` and `geom_point()`, the latter will override the former, so you are essentially plotting the full dataset in both plots.

```
a_list_of_charts[[i]] <- ggplot(df %>% 
                                  filter(variable == names(a_list_of_colours)[i]), 
                                aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable),
             shape = 19, size = 2, 
             colour = a_list_of_colours[[names(a_list_of_colours)[i]]])
```

## Loop 3

This code works to show the right data subset with the right colour. Though if you want a legend as well, Loop 1's a better bet (assuming you are able to update your package version).